# Аутентификация с помощью Laravel Breeze

Tags: php, laravel

Новичок в Ларе, а с выходом 8-ой версии появился некий стартовый пакет аутентификации пользователя Laravel Breeze. Установил, чутка подверстал шаблоны и все, дальше как с ним работать - не понятно. Задача такая, сделать вход под студентом. Следовательно у меня есть таблица Students, туда я уже вписал email, password и remember_token, пароль у всех стандартный 1111. Как мне поменять конфигурацию Breeze-а, чтобы он обращался к таблице students и смотрел на неё. Сейчас я так понимаю он смотрит на таблицу users.

Comment: Уже и фабрикой создал 100 юзеров в таблице Users  и попробовал по их email адресу и паролю войти - тоже нет, скорее всего какая то настройка сбита изначально... Такого быть не должно

Comment: Вам наверняка нужно добавить новый User Provider в config/auth.php. По умолчанию используется модель `App\Models\User::class`, Breeze должен же откуда-то узнать, что ему нужно работать не с моделью User

Comment: Уже делал так, тоже не помогает, возможно это работает только если пользователь прошел через регистрацию, а через фабрики и сидеры не пойдет задавать пароли ?

Comment: Вообще я так понимаю это все делается на пустом проекте , а я решил уже в середине сделать и у меня почему то не подклбчаются app/css и app/js